# Dynamic variable naming in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have looked around for a while and did not seem to find an 'elegant' solution to my problem, hopefully someone can provide some help.

Very briefly my problem is: I would like to be able to name multiple variables with only difference an 'index' number. These numbers are however not continuous.

Roughly, I am trying to attempt something as follows:

```
fileNumbers={332,333,337,345,346};
int i=0;
Do{
i = current_list_item;
fileNumRi = Import[...];
slopeRi = fileNumR[[2]];
... etc ...
}While(inside the list)
```

I would then end up with the variables fileNumR332, fileNumR333, etc...

Currently my only solution is a lot of copy pasting, but this is getting very tedious and generates too many chances for a mistake via typo.

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Ronan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard solution would be to use variables `fileNumR[1], fileNumR[2], fileNumR[3]...`, like this:

```
Do[
  (
     fileNumR[i]=Import[...];
     slopeR[i] = fileNumR[i][[2]];
  ), {i, fileNumbers}];
```

(And since you seem to be unsure about Mathematica's syntax, I'd like to suggest [this collection of useful links](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/242).)

Comment: I will be honest, at this point I don't know if I should hate myself for missing this or love you for showing it to me... perhaps a bit of both.

Regardless, many thanks for the answer (and the link). I had no idea you could use "Do" in a selective manner like that. This solves oh so many of my time loss issues.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, likely preferred approach is to work with lists. The equivalent to the 'Do' loop becomes something like this:

```
 fileNumbers = {332, 333, 337, 345, 346};
 listofcontents=Import["basename" <> ToString[#] <> ".dat"] & /@ fileNumbers;
```

Your individual data sets are then referenced using `Part` notation, eg:

```
 listofcontents[[1,2]]
```

a downside here is the indices are sequential {1,2,3,4,5} and should you need to directly  use the original file numbers you'd need something like:

```
 MapIndexed[ (fn[#] = First@#2) & , fileNumbers];
 listofcontents[[fn[332],2]]
```

In most cases the efficiency gained coding with lists will outweigh that bit of cumbersome notation however.

For completeness the answer to your literal question is to work with `ToExpression`, eg:

```
 data = Import[...];
 ToExpression[ "filenum" <> ToString[i] <> " = data "]
```

you end up with symbols named filenum332 , etc.  Its such a convoluted way to work you very rarely do such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Making some test data first

```
fileNumbers = {332, 333, 337, 345, 346};

Export[ToString[#], {{1, 2, 3}, {"slopedata", #}}, "CSV"] & /@ fileNumbers
```

Method 1: using function variables (like nikie's solution)

```
Map[(fileNumR[#] = Import[ToString[#]];
    slopeR[#] = fileNumR[#][[2]]) &, fileNumbers];
```

E.g. checking the output from one variable

```
slopeR[337]
```

> {slopedata,337}

Method 2: creating variables as originally specified by the OP

```
Map[(Evaluate[Symbol[StringJoin["fileNumR", ToString[#]]]] = Import[ToString[#]];
    Evaluate[Symbol[StringJoin["slopeR", ToString[#]]]] =
     Symbol[StringJoin["fileNumR", ToString[#]]][[2]]) &, fileNumbers];
```

Again checking the output from one variable

```
slopeR337
```

> {slopedata,337}

To repeat the process in the same session the variables need to be cleared in advance.

```
Map[(Clear @@ Names[StringJoin["fileNumR", ToString[#]]];
    Evaluate[Symbol[StringJoin["fileNumR", ToString[#]]]] = Import[ToString[#]];
    Clear @@ Names[StringJoin["slopeR", ToString[#]]];
    Evaluate[Symbol[StringJoin["slopeR", ToString[#]]]] =
     Symbol[StringJoin["fileNumR", ToString[#]]][[2]]) &, fileNumbers];
```

Finally, if you by any chance need convert `fileNumR337` to `fileNumR[337]` see this post :- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38767/363